# Problema ao acessar valores em um dicionário - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho um dicionário que funciona da seguinte forma:

```
{'0': {'Nome': 'Marcos', 'ID': 99984}, '1': {'Nome': 'Julia', 'ID': 99983}, '2': {'Nome': 'Carlos', 'ID': 99982}}
```

Como dá para ver cada `chave` no dicionário inicial possui como `valor` um outro dicionário que por sua vez possui as chaves `Nome` e `ID`.

Eu estou tentando verificar se tal nome existe no dicionário, para isso fiz esse código:

```
if "Marcos" in meu_dicionario:
    print("Esse nome existe!")
else:
    print("Esse nome não existe!")
```

"Marcos" existe no dicionário, mas sempre recebo a mensagem `Esse nome não existe!`.

Como eu poderia estar fazendo essa verificação?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O operador `in` verifica as chaves do dicionário, que no caso são `'0'`, `'1'` e `'2'`. Por isso seu código não funciona, pois está verificando se o dicionário possui a chave "Marcos". Mas "Marcos" é um valor (não uma chave), e nem está no dicionário principal (ele está dentro de um dos dicionários internos).

Ou seja, se for pra procurar nos nomes, você tem que verificar os valores (os dicionários internos):

```py
meu_dicionario = {'0': {'Nome': 'Marcos', 'ID': 99984}, '1': {'Nome': 'Julia', 'ID': 99983}, '2': {'Nome': 'Carlos', 'ID': 99982}}

# se algum dos dicionários internos tem o nome que procuro 
if any(d['Nome'] == 'Marcos' for d in meu_dicionario.values()):
    print("Esse nome existe!")
else:
    print("Esse nome não existe!")
```

`values()` retorna os valores do dicionário (que no caso são os dicionários internos, os que possuem "Nome").

Depois eu uso `any` passando uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) que verifica se algum desses dicionários tem o nome que estou buscando.

---

Se quiser também pode usar um loop simples:

```py
for d in meu_dicionario.values():
    if d['Nome'] == 'Marcos':
        print("Esse nome existe!")
        break # se já encontrou, interrompe o loop
else:
    print("Esse nome não existe!")
```

Lembrando que o `else` acima é do `for`, não do `if` (ele entra no `else` se o loop não é interrompido por um `break`, ou seja, se não encontrar o nome).

---

Por fim, reveja se precisa mesmo de um dicionário. Se as chaves são números sequenciais começando do zero, talvez uma lista seja mais adequada...

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar um generator, que te permite criar uma sequência de elementos sem de fato armazená-los em memória, apenas sendo criados quando necessário. Desta forma, a partir do seu dicionário, você consegue uma sequência com os nomes e então fica fácil utilizar o operador `in` para verificar se o nome desejado se encontra no dicionário.

Criando uma função para realizar essa consulta, vc consegue reutilizar e melhorar a legibilidade do seu código.

```
meu_dicionario = {'0': {'Nome': 'Marcos', 'ID': 99984}, '1': {'Nome': 'Julia', 'ID': 99983}, '2': {'Nome': 'Carlos', 'ID': 99982}}

    
def find_person_by_name(name: str) -> bool:
    names = (meu_dicionario[person]['Nome'] for person in meu_dicionario)
    
    if name in names:
        print('Existe')
        return True
        
    print('Não existe')
    return False
    
    
find_person_by_name('Marcos')
# Existe

find_person_by_name('Nathan')
# Não existe
```